# Cannot import sparkdl into databricks notebook

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning, databricks

As I said in the title, I cannot import sparkdl module into databricks.
I followed step by step this official tutorial [sparkdl tutorial](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/5669198905533692/3647723071348946/3983381308530741/latest.html) but when I simply put some code like:

```
from sparkdl import readImages
```

I get an error that says I cannot import readImages from sparkdl, the same for other classes such DeepImageFeaturizer.

I checked and It seems there is some sort of problem with the versions of keras,tensorflow,sparkdl,h5py and the maven library spark-deep-learning so I'm looking for a stable combination beetween them.
Taking into account that from Databricks I can only install tensorflow from 2.5.0 up to newer version.

With the following versions:

```
tensorflow v 2.5.0, keras 2.2.4, 1.4.0-spark-deep-learning,h5py v 3.7.0
```

I Got the following error while importing DeepImageFeaturizer

```
from sparkdl import DeepImageFeaturizer ImportError: cannot import name 'resnet50' from 'keras.applications' (/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/keras/applications/__init__.py)
```

Any help or suggestion will be really appreciated

Comment: How did you install the libraries into Databricks cluster?

Comment: through Computes->Click on cluster name -> Libraries Tab -> search for the maven library/pyPI module